# How to get GWT DatePickerCell Panel with Time options

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I am trying to use GWT DatePickerCell in my CellTable, I want to display DatePicker Panel with time options on clicking the Cell? how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no time picker in GWT. I wrote a Time picker that accepts almost any time format and converts it to a millisecond value. You can use that and extend `AbstractEditableCell` to use it in a cell.

It attempts to create a HTML5 `<input type="time"/>` and if it's not supported by the browser, it parses manually. I have tested it on Chrome and Firefox on PC, and iOS.

Accepted formats are:

- 12:59 AM
- 5 - assumed to be 5 AM
- 5p - 5:00 PM
- 13 - 1 PM
- 345 - 3:45 AM
- 1534 - 3:34 PM
- 111p - 1:11 PM

it implements `HasValue<Long>` to return the picked time as milliseconds. It also has a method to return the time combined with a given `Date` object.

Here's the source: https://github.com/srilankanchurro/gwt-stuff/blob/master/gwt-stuff/src/com/sathkumara/client/client/TimePicker.java

If you have modifications to contribute to this class, please feel free to send me a request on github.